# scraping javascript buttons in R

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, phantomjs

I would like to download a large number of csv files from a web page written in what seems to be javascript.  Each page has a button labelled 'csv' which downloads the file.  Pretty simple but I don't understand the javascript on the page well enough to know how to identify the button, or know how to download the file.  Here is a sample page:

https://votaciones.hcdn.gob.ar/diputado/1

I would prefer an R solution but python would work in a pinch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, this worked:

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://votaciones.hcdn.gob.ar/diputado/1")
button <- remDr$findElements("class", "buttons-html5")
button[[2]]$clickElement()
```